# I'm having trouble running Flutter on Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu

[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Kej.png)

Ubuntu, the problem of running the application in Flutter.
This problem is in Ubuntu.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the doctor says what's wrong: you have to run those `apt install ...` what he mentioned about

Comment: I just installed Android Studio and uploaded a raw project, but Doctor Flutter gives these errors and the program does not run.

Comment: open android studio -> sdkmanager and install `cmdline-tools` and `build-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install android studio and set environment variables correctly.